# How to start new numeration of theorems with every chapter?

Tags: numbering, miktex, theorems, texstudio

What I want? [that way of numbering]

```
1   How to do squats

Theorem 1. Put your barbell on your shoulders.
Theorem 2. Squat.

2   How to do bench press

Theorem 1. Lean on a bench.
Theorem 2. Push.
```

What I get

[image]

with this MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[russian]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}

\section{How to do squats}

\begin{theorem}\normalfont
Put your barbell on your shoulders.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}\normalfont
Squat.
\end{theorem}

\section{How to do bench press}

\begin{theorem}\normalfont
Lean on a bench.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}\normalfont
Push.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: if you're using `amsthm`, why specify `\normalfont`?  the same effect is gained by defining `theorem` using `\theoremstyle{definition}`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, thanks. It is really useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the following to your code

```
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{theorem}{section}
\makeatother
```

and now the working version

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[russian]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{theorem}{section}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{How to do squats}

\begin{theorem}\normalfont
Put your barbell on your shoulders.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}\normalfont
 Squat.
\end{theorem}

\section{How to do bench press}

\begin{theorem}\normalfont
 Lean on a bench.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}\normalfont
 Push.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes. This is what I really wanted. Thank you!

Comment: to avoid `\normalfont`, define `theorem` (or some alternate name) using `\theoremstyle{definition}`.  much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

`\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]`

`\newtheorem` actually has three different syntaxes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However I am aware of the number of arguments of this environment. And if you try this on, you will get the double number 1.1; 1.2; 2.1; 2.2 and so on.

Comment: @VladimirYashin Just add `\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\arabic{theorem}}`; you're doing a bad service to your readers, though, because they'll have to look up what section they're in when browsing for a cross reference.

Comment: @egreg, yes, I totally agree with you. However this is not for publishing and using at all. Lets assume that I have to do it exactly like that.